# What is the correct way to solve this ordinary differential equation decay problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently studying the textbook *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Morris Tenenbaum and Harry Pollard. The section **LESSON 1. How Differential Equations Originate.** has the following exercise:

> 1. The radium in a piece of lead decomposes at a rate which is proportional to the amount present. If 10 percent of the radium decomposes in 200 years, what percent of the original amount of radium will be present in a piece of lead after 1000 years?

The answer is said to be 59.05 percent.

Let $x$ be the amount of radium. Since the amount of radium in a piece of lead *decomposes* at a rate which is *proportional* to the amount present, we have the differential equation $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -kx$, where $k > 0$ is a constant of proportionality.

Using the usual algebraic manipulations and then integration, we get that $x = Ae^{-kt}$, where $A$ is a constant.

So we now need to find the values of the constants, $A$ and $k$. Since we are told that 10 percent of the radium decomposes in 200 years, it seems to me that we have $0.9x = Ae^{-200k}$; but this still doesn't allow us to find $A$ and $k$. So what am I misunderstanding here? And what is the correct way to solve this?

---

### EDIT

When $t = 0$, we have that $x = A$.

If I'm not mistaken, By plugging in $t = 0$ and concluding that $x = A$, this means that $x = A$ for all $t$, since $A$ is constant.

So we have that $$0.9x = xe^{-200k} \Rightarrow \dfrac{\ln(0.9)}{-200} = k = 0.00053$$

If we say that $C$ is the percent of the original amount of radium after $t$ years, then we have that $$Cx = xe^{-1000(0.00053)} \Rightarrow C = 0.5886,$$ which is 58.86% – not 59.05, as the textbook states.

Comment: Note - the only problem with your solution is that you are rounding too much too early.  If you use more decimal points, and set $k = 0.0005268$, you get the same value as the book.

Comment: @johnnyb You're right; thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug in $t=0$ into the solution you get, you will have $x=Ae^0=A$. So you have value for $A$. For $k$, as you have shown, you have $0.9x=xe^{-200k}$. So you have
$$-200k=\ln(0.9).$$
When you consider the case after 1000 years, you have
$$-1000k=5\ln(0.9)=\ln(0.9^5).$$
So you will see
$$e^{-1000k}=0.9^5.$$
This is the percent you are looking for.

Comment: By plugging in $t = 0$ and concluding that $x = A$, this means that $x = A$ for all $t$, since $A$ is constant?

Comment: Also, I don't see how it makes sense to say that finding a solution to the problem does not require $k$. Furthermore, if we say that $C$ is the percent of the original amount of radium after $t$ years, then we have that $$Cx = xe^{-1000(0.00053)} \Rightarrow C = 0.5886,$$ which is 58.86% – not 59.05, as the textbook states.

Comment: For the first comment, I used the same notation you use in the problem. In that case, $x$ denotes the initial amount of radium which is a constant. For the second comment, I typed something wrong, sorry! You can solve $k$ actually like what I did.  And finally you can get $C=0.9^5\approx 0.59049$ which should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is the starting amount of radium and $x$ is the current amount of radium.  Therefore, $0.9$ is $\frac{x}{A}$.  Use that to solve for $k$, and use the same idea to then extrapolate to a different $\frac{x}{A}$ for a different $t$.